# How can i fix my displacement map. Its too big

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers, displacement

I have  a logo design that i put into blender and i want to edit it with a displacement map. but when i add it to my material it is really big and i have it on the lowest scale and i havent even added a texture yet. how can i fix this? i just started working with blender so i have no clue
[image]

Comment: The scale actually can go lower. Just click the box and type in a smaller number.

Comment: also you can insert "math" into any number in nodes.. If there is 0.100, you can add "/10" and that will divide 0.100 by 10.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sanbaldo pointed out, you can multiply the values.

1. Add a *Math* node and set it to *Multiply*
2. Enter 0,001 and connect it into the *Scale* input.
3. Values you type into the second field, will be multiplied by that 0,001

(You can of course use *Divide* instead, if you want :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much 